# Code playground (like CodePen) inside WordPress?

Tags: embed

I've reached exhaustion in trying to find a solution to my problem. And the problem is that I want to display custom HTML/CSS snippets inside of my WordPress blog posts (e.g. be able to render them and let readers interact with them) without using an embed like CodePen or JSFiddle.

Let's say I wanted to add an example of a grid container and then let users resize it directly inside the article itself.

Does anyone have any ideas or tips on how to achieve my desired result? I am honestly not opposed to paying for a premium plugin that does this if there is any. It's just that I want to avoid using embeds as much as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: If you refuse to use a third party embed then you're going to need to write your own code editor with live preview, which is: A. A lot more work than you seem to be expecting, B. beyond the scope of a single question, and C. mostly nothing to do with WordPress. There may be plugins or libraries out there that can help you with this, but recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Hey Jacob, I completely overcomplicated my issue to be honest. First of all, the "Add HTML" block works just fine for embedding CSS & HTML snippets inside the post container (it even respects the container). And, second, the most important feature for me was that readers can resize the container to see the real-time effect of changing the container viewport. And this was an easy fix with the `resize: horizontal;` CSS property. Admittedly, it's not so great for mobile but I can live with that. Thanks for the reply, though!

Comment: I see. Because of your examples I thought you wanted to let users resize it _with code_. That’s my misunderstanding.

Comment: There u go https://github.com/mosheKerbel/react-codepen Custom build codepen in react